# Wordpress child theme, sections disappear

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm creating a child theme of Quality (https://wordpress.org/themes/quality/). I´m using the Business Template for the main page.

These are the sections of the template in Quality:

[image]

And these ones are the sections of my child theme:

[image]

As can be seen, most of the sections disappeared in the child theme.

How can I use those sections in my theme?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like theres something thats already added when you are using the Quality template, which isn't activated in your child theme.

Isn't there some kind of setting page, where you can enable stuff like this?

Maybe under "Appearance" in the wordpress backend menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had not found any option to change that in the menu before post my question.

It does not seem to be a WordPress problem, but theme problem